# Copy file contents to temporary file for download PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to take a file that have stored in my file manager and copy it's contents to a new temporary file that when you hit a download button it allows you to download the temporary file and it doesn't overwrite the existing file on my file manager.

This is what I have right now for just downloading the file after clicking a button on a previous page.

```
<?php
$file = "freewill.doc";

if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

$type = filetype($file);
// Get a date and timestamp
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$time = time();
// Send file headers
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$session->username}.txt");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0');
// Send the file contents.
set_time_limit(0); 
readfile($file);
?>
```

I want it to replace the string in the old file to a new one so it doesn't overwrite, so multiple people could do it. So I have a form that asks for name. I have a string placeholder that will put the name where the placeholder is. If it does it to the existing one, only one person would do it and it would stay like that. So it would be like "I, Xxx x xxX, would like to..." and replace that string into a temporary file so the Xxx stays in tact on the old file.

Comment: i dont understand why you need to copy it, and not just serve it from what ever its current location is

Comment: Why would you want to waste IO on copying to a temporary file instead of doing exactly what you've already posted which is an objectively good idea?

Comment: I'm trying to replace it with a temporary one because I'm trying to replace a certain string in the file and I don't want it to replace the string from the main file. I want it to replace the string in the old file to a new one so it doesn't overwrite, so multiple people could do it. So I have a form that asks for name. I have a string placeholder that will put the name where the placeholder is. If it does it to the existing one, only one person would do it and it would stay like that.

Comment: read file, replace string, serve the text you did the replacement on as the file, no need to copy or make a new file